# Out-of-bounds warning on dereferenced pointer

Tags: c, pointers, indexoutofboundsexception, static-analysis

Please consider the following C struct implementing a very simple ring buffer:

```
struct shm_buffer_s {
    pthread_mutex_t shm_mutex;
    uint16_t head;
    uint16_t tail;
    struct shm_node_s node[SHM_NODES_MAX];
};
```

Then I have a function to push a new dataset into the buffer:

```
uint32_t PushDataset(const struct shm_dataset_s *dataset, struct shm_buffer_s *const input_buf)
{
    uint32_t return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_ERROR;
    uint16_t head_index = 0;
    size_t payload_size = 0;

    if((dataset == NULL) || (input_buf == NULL)){
        return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_NULL_ERROR;
    }
    else if(pthread_mutex_lock(&input_buf->shm_mutex) != 0){
        return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_MUTEX_ERROR;
    }
    else{
        head_index = input_buf->head;
        /* ...Rest of the function... */
    }

    return return_value;
}/*PushDataset*/
```

Static analysis is flagging that derefence for `head` as a potential out-of-bounds error. The whole program works fine, the caller of the function reserves memory for `input_buf` correctly and I don't get errors like this in, for example, the "Pop" version, which looks like this:

```
SI_32 PopDataset(struct shm_dataset_s *const dataset, struct shm_buffer_s *const output_buf)
{
    SI_32 return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_ERROR;
    UI_16 tail_index = 0;
    size_t payload_size = 0;

    if((dataset == NULL) || (output_buf == NULL)){
        return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_NULL_ERROR;
    }
    else if(pthread_mutex_lock(&output_buf->shm_mutex) != 0){
        return_value = MEM_MGMT_SHM_MUTEX_ERROR;
    }
    else{
        /* Clear output dataset in case it wasn't initialized */
        memset(dataset, 0, sizeof(struct shm_dataset_s));

        tail_index = output_buf->tail;

        /* ...Rest of the function... */

    return return_value;
}/*PopDataset*/
```

The memory areas pointed to by `struct shm_buffer_s *` are shared memory areas created by the caller of the functions.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. How do you create the shared memory areas? How do you initialize that memory? How do you get a single structure element from that memory?

Comment: what if you change declaration of `PopDataset` to `SI_32 PopDataset(struct shm_dataset_s *const dataset, const struct shm_buffer_s * output_buf)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude apologies, I have read the link and I'll have to come up with a different way of presenting the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Frankie_C I don't think that would work because once I get the dataset I need to update the contents of `output_buf`

Comment: The request was to just understand how the compiler reacts.